# Automatically detect changes in a database using Ajax

Tags: ajax

I want to make an online DB based chat application. My problem is to detect changes in the DB, i.e. whenever a user sends a message to another user it should display to him. One approach is Ajax calls with `setinterval` but I want an instant solution. I do not want to keep the server busy with such Ajax calls.

Comment: What did you try so far? It would be very helpful if you laid out your approach first, maybe with some code snippets you tried! Please be also more specific: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: use push or pull frameworks (push would be the better option here)